# Java Exception not understood

Tags: java, class, oop, search-engine

I am writing a search engine code using java, and I'm getting this error without knowing the cause:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WriteToFile.fileWriter(WriteToFile.java:29)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is my code :

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Search {

   private static String URL="https://www.google.com/search?q=";
   private Document doc;
   private Elements links;
   private String html;

   public Search() throws IOException {};


   public void SearchWeb() throws IOException {

       //to get the keywords from the user

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please enter the keyword you want to search for: ");
       String word = sc.nextLine();


       //Search for the keyword over the net

       String url = URL + word;
       doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
       html = doc.html();



       Files.write(Paths.get("D:\\OOP\\OOPproj\\data.txt"), html.getBytes());

        links = doc.select("cite");


   }

   public Document getDoc() {
       return doc;
   }

   public String getHtml() {
       return html;
   }

   public Elements getLinks() {
       return links;
   }
}
```

and this is the class writeToFile:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class WriteToFile extends Search {

    public WriteToFile() throws IOException {};

    String description = "<!> Could not fetch description <!>";
    String keywords = "<!> Could not fetch keywords <!>";
    private ArrayList<String> detail = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedWriter bw = null;


        public void fileWriter() throws IOException {




            for (Element link : super.getLinks()) {
                String text = link.text();
                if (text.contains("›")) {
                    text = text.replaceAll(" › ", "/");
                }

                detail.add(text);
                System.out.println(text);


            }

            System.out.println("***************************************************");

            for (int i = 0; i < detail.size(); i++)
                System.out.println("detail [" + (i + 1) + "]" + detail.get(i));

            System.out.println("###################################################################");

            for (int j = 0; j < detail.size(); j++) {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(detail.get(j)).get();
                String web = document.html();
                Document d = Jsoup.parse(web);

                Elements metaTags = d.getElementsByTag("meta");
                for (Element metaTag : metaTags) {
                    String content = metaTag.attr("content");
                    String name = metaTag.attr("name");

                    if ("description".equals(name)) {
                        description = content;

                    }


                    if ("keywords".equals(name)) {
                        keywords = content;

                    }

                }

                String title = d.title();
                Files.write(Paths.get("D:\\OOP\\OOPproj\\search.txt"), (detail.get(j) + "\t" + "|" + "\t" + title + "\t" + "|" + "\t" + description + "\t" + "|" + "\t" + keywords + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            }

        }
}
```

This is the Main class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Search a = new Search();
        a.SearchWeb(); 
        WriteToFile b = new WriteToFile();
        b.fileWriter();
    }
}
```

I tried to print the getLinks() method in main to check if it was null , but it wasn't , the links were cited.
I would be really grateful if someone helps me out.

Comment: Which line is line 29? From a quick look, `link` could be null in `link.text()` or `text` could be null in `text.contains(",")`, if the error comes from around there.

Comment: this is line 29 ```for (Element link : super.getLinks())```

Comment: Then `getLinks()` must return null. Try printing the result of `getLinks()` right before the for-loop in `fileWriter()` to confirm that.

Comment: You are right it does return null. But why? when I printed it in the main it gave me the links

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that the links are initialized by the `SearchWeb()` method, so that must be called before `fileWriter()`.

Comment: The issue is in that code, I added it to your question and posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `SearchWeb()` on object `a`, but you're calling `fileWriter()` on object `b`. This means the links are set in `a`, but not in `b`.

Since `WriteToFile` extends `Search`, you just need an instance of that:

```
WriteToFile a = new WriteToFile();
a.SearchWeb();
a.fileWriter();
```